# Using Apache Spark for UDP

Tags: java, port, bigdata, apache-spark

I'm new to Apache Spark.

I'm receiving data at my UDP port 8060, I want to capture it and perform some operations in the real time, for which I'm using Spark Streaming.
Here is my Main class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("NetworkWordCount");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(1000));
        JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = jssc.receiverStream(new CustomReceiver("localhost",8060));
        JavaDStream<String> hash = lines.flatMap(
                  new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                        @Override public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
                      //    System.out.println(x);
                            String[] s=x.split("\\}\\{");
                          return Arrays.asList(s);

                      }
            });
        hash.print();
        jssc.start();
    }
}
```

And CustomReceiver class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver;

public class CustomReceiver extends Receiver<String> {

      String host = null;
      int port = -1;


      public CustomReceiver(String host_ , int port_) {
        super(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2());
        host = host_;
        port = port_;
      }

      public void onStart() {
        // Start the thread that receives data over a connection

        new Thread()  {
          @Override public void run() {
            receive();
          }
        }.start();
      }

      public void onStop() {
        // There is nothing much to do as the thread calling receive()
        // is designed to stop by itself isStopped() returns false
      }

      /** Create a socket connection and receive data until receiver is stopped */
      private void receive() {
        DatagramSocket socket = null;
        String userInput = null;

        try {
          // connect to the server
          socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
          byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
          DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
          socket.receive(receivePacket);
          userInput = new String( receivePacket.getData());
      //    System.out.println(userInput);
          // Until stopped or connection broken continue reading


    //        System.out.println(userInput);
              store(userInput);

          socket.close();

          // Restart in an attempt to connect again when server is active again
          restart("Trying to connect again");
        } catch(ConnectException ce) {
          // restart if could not connect to server
          restart("Could not connect", ce);
        } catch(Throwable t) {
          // restart if there is any other error
          restart("Error receiving data", t);
        }
      }
    }
```

The code loops but as soon as I send the data, I get a weird error and it stops working:

```
15/01/20 17:44:53 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: gautambajaj
15/01/20 17:44:53 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: gautambajaj
15/01/20 17:44:53 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(gautambajaj); users with modify permissions: Set(gautambajaj)
15/01/20 17:44:54 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/01/20 17:44:55 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/01/20 17:44:55 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.34.71.121:63919]
15/01/20 17:44:55 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.34.71.121:63919]
15/01/20 17:44:55 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 63919.
15/01/20 17:44:55 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/01/20 17:44:55 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/01/20 17:44:55 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /var/folders/z3/347_jn996097tyhzl905tm7m0000gn/T/spark-local-20150120174455-e4cf
15/01/20 17:44:56 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'Connection manager for block manager' on port 63920.
15/01/20 17:44:56 INFO network.ConnectionManager: Bound socket to port 63920 with id = ConnectionManagerId(10.34.71.121,63920)
15/01/20 17:44:56 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 818.5 MB
15/01/20 17:44:56 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/01/20 17:44:56 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager 10.34.71.121:63920 with 818.5 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(<driver>, 10.34.71.121, 63920, 0)
15/01/20 17:44:56 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/01/20 17:44:56 INFO spark.HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /var/folders/z3/347_jn996097tyhzl905tm7m0000gn/T/spark-9737478e-492e-44c6-accc-e8a7c91b2ab3
15/01/20 17:44:56 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/01/20 17:44:56 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
15/01/20 17:44:56 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:63921
15/01/20 17:44:56 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 63921.
15/01/20 17:44:57 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
15/01/20 17:44:57 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
15/01/20 17:44:57 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/01/20 17:44:57 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.34.71.121:4040
2015-01-20 17:44:57.460 java[17010:1404608] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
15/01/20 17:44:57 INFO util.AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.34.71.121:63919/user/HeartbeatReceiver
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: ReceiverTracker started
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.ForEachDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.FlatMappedDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Slide time = 1000 ms
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Remember duration = 1000 ms
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.PluggableInputDStream@e039859
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.FlatMappedDStream: Slide time = 1000 ms
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.FlatMappedDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.FlatMappedDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.FlatMappedDStream: Remember duration = 1000 ms
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.FlatMappedDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FlatMappedDStream@6e247d4a
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.ForEachDStream: Slide time = 1000 ms
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.ForEachDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.ForEachDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.ForEachDStream: Remember duration = 1000 ms
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO dstream.ForEachDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@5f159e0c
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Starting 1 receivers
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: start at Main.java:76
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (start at Main.java:76) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 0(start at Main.java:76)
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO util.RecurringTimer: Started timer for JobGenerator at time 1421743499000
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO scheduler.JobGenerator: Started JobGenerator at 1421743499000 ms
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Started JobScheduler
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/01/20 17:44:58 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 0 (ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at start at Main.java:76), which has no missing parents
15/01/20 17:44:59 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:44:59 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743499000 ms
15/01/20 17:44:59 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421743499000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743499000 ms
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1421743499000 ms
-------------------------------------------

15/01/20 17:44:59 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421743499000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743499000 ms
15/01/20 17:44:59 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.302 s for time 1421743499000 ms (execution: 0.069 s)
15/01/20 17:45:00 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:00 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743500000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:00 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421743500000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743500000 ms
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1421743500000 ms
-------------------------------------------

15/01/20 17:45:00 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421743500000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743500000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:00 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.005 s for time 1421743500000 ms (execution: 0.001 s)
15/01/20 17:45:00 INFO rdd.FlatMappedRDD: Removing RDD 2 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:00 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 2
15/01/20 17:45:00 INFO rdd.BlockRDD: Removing RDD 1 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:00 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 1
15/01/20 17:45:00 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[1] at receiverStream at Main.java:30 of time 1421743500000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743501000 ms
-------------------------------------------15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421743501000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743501000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421743501000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743501000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO rdd.FlatMappedRDD: Removing RDD 4 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.004 s for time 1421743501000 ms (execution: 0.000 s)

Time: 1421743501000 ms
-------------------------------------------

15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 4
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO rdd.BlockRDD: Removing RDD 3 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 3
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[3] at receiverStream at Main.java:30 of time 1421743501000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1216) called with curMem=0, maxMem=858229309
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 1216.0 B, free 818.5 MB)
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from Stage 0 (ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at start at Main.java:76)
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1558 bytes)
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Registered receiver 0
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO util.RecurringTimer: Started timer for BlockGenerator at time 1421743502000
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Started block pushing thread
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Started BlockGenerator
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Starting receiver
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver onStart
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Registered receiver for stream 0 from akka://sparkDriver
15/01/20 17:45:01 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Registered receiver for stream 0 from akka://sparkDriver
15/01/20 17:45:02 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:02 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743502000 ms
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1421743502000 ms
-------------------------------------------

15/01/20 17:45:02 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421743502000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743502000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:02 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421743502000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743502000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:02 INFO rdd.FlatMappedRDD: Removing RDD 6 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:02 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.004 s for time 1421743502000 ms (execution: 0.000 s)
15/01/20 17:45:02 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 6
15/01/20 17:45:02 INFO rdd.BlockRDD: Removing RDD 5 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:02 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 5
15/01/20 17:45:02 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[5] at receiverStream at Main.java:30 of time 1421743502000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:03 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:03 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743503000 ms
-------------------------------------------
15/01/20 17:45:03 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421743503000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743503000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:03 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421743503000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743503000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:03 INFO rdd.FlatMappedRDD: Removing RDD 8 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:03 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.006 s for time 1421743503000 ms (execution: 0.000 s)
15/01/20 17:45:03 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 8
15/01/20 17:45:03 INFO rdd.BlockRDD: Removing RDD 7 from persistence list
Time: 1421743503000 ms
-------------------------------------------

15/01/20 17:45:03 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 7
15/01/20 17:45:03 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[7] at receiverStream at Main.java:30 of time 1421743503000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:04 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:04 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743504000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:04 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421743504000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743504000 ms
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1421743504000 ms
-------------------------------------------

15/01/20 17:45:04 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421743504000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743504000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:04 INFO rdd.FlatMappedRDD: Removing RDD 10 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:04 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.007 s for time 1421743504000 ms (execution: 0.000 s)
15/01/20 17:45:04 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 10
15/01/20 17:45:04 INFO rdd.BlockRDD: Removing RDD 9 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:04 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 9
15/01/20 17:45:04 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[9] at receiverStream at Main.java:30 of time 1421743504000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:05 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:05 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743505000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:05 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421743505000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743505000 ms
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1421743505000 ms
-------------------------------------------

15/01/20 17:45:05 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421743505000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743505000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:05 INFO rdd.FlatMappedRDD: Removing RDD 12 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:05 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.006 s for time 1421743505000 ms (execution: 0.000 s)
15/01/20 17:45:05 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 12
15/01/20 17:45:05 INFO rdd.BlockRDD: Removing RDD 11 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:05 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 11
15/01/20 17:45:05 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[11] at receiverStream at Main.java:30 of time 1421743505000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:06 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:06 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743506000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:06 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421743506000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743506000 ms
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1421743506000 ms
-------------------------------------------

15/01/20 17:45:06 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421743506000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743506000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:06 INFO rdd.FlatMappedRDD: Removing RDD 14 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:06 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.004 s for time 1421743506000 ms (execution: 0.000 s)
15/01/20 17:45:06 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 14
15/01/20 17:45:06 INFO rdd.BlockRDD: Removing RDD 13 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:06 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 13
15/01/20 17:45:06 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[13] at receiverStream at Main.java:30 of time 1421743506000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:07 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:07 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743507000 ms
-------------------------------------------
15/01/20 17:45:07 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421743507000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743507000 ms
Time: 1421743507000 ms
-------------------------------------------

15/01/20 17:45:07 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421743507000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743507000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:07 INFO rdd.FlatMappedRDD: Removing RDD 16 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:07 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.004 s for time 1421743507000 ms (execution: 0.001 s)
15/01/20 17:45:07 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 16
15/01/20 17:45:07 INFO rdd.BlockRDD: Removing RDD 15 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:07 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 15
15/01/20 17:45:07 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[15] at receiverStream at Main.java:30 of time 1421743507000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:08 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:08 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743508000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:08 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421743508000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743508000 ms
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1421743508000 ms
-------------------------------------------
15/01/20 17:45:08 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421743508000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743508000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:08 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.004 s for time 1421743508000 ms (execution: 0.000 s)
15/01/20 17:45:08 INFO rdd.FlatMappedRDD: Removing RDD 18 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:08 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 18

15/01/20 17:45:08 INFO rdd.BlockRDD: Removing RDD 17 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:08 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 17
15/01/20 17:45:08 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[17] at receiverStream at Main.java:30 of time 1421743508000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743509000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421743509000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743509000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421743509000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743509000 ms
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1421743509000 ms
-------------------------------------------

15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO rdd.FlatMappedRDD: Removing RDD 20 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.011 s for time 1421743509000 ms (execution: 0.000 s)
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 20
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO rdd.BlockRDD: Removing RDD 19 from persistence list
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 19
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO dstream.PluggableInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[19] at receiverStream at Main.java:30 of time 1421743509000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:09 WARN receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Restarting receiver with delay 2000 ms: Trying to connect again
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopping receiver with message: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Trying to connect again: 
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver onStop
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Deregistering receiver 0
15/01/20 17:45:09 ERROR scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Trying to connect again
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopped receiver 0
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2120) called with curMem=1216, maxMem=858229309
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1421743509200 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.1 KB, free 818.5 MB)
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1421743509200 in memory on 10.34.71.121:63920 (size: 2.1 KB, free: 818.5 MB)
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block input-0-1421743509200
15/01/20 17:45:09 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1421743509200 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
15/01/20 17:45:09 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1421743509200
15/01/20 17:45:10 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 1 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:10 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743510000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:10 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421743510000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421743510000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:10 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: getCallSite at DStream.scala:294
15/01/20 17:45:10 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (getCallSite at DStream.scala:294) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=true)
15/01/20 17:45:10 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 1(getCallSite at DStream.scala:294)
15/01/20 17:45:10 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/01/20 17:45:10 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/01/20 17:45:10 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 1 (FlatMappedRDD[24] at flatMap at Main.java:32), which has no missing parents
15/01/20 17:45:10 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1800) called with curMem=3336, maxMem=858229309
15/01/20 17:45:10 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 1800.0 B, free 818.5 MB)
15/01/20 17:45:10 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from Stage 1 (FlatMappedRDD[24] at flatMap at Main.java:32)
15/01/20 17:45:10 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
15/01/20 17:45:11 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:11 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743511000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:11 INFO receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Starting receiver again
15/01/20 17:45:11 INFO receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Starting receiver
15/01/20 17:45:11 INFO receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver onStart
15/01/20 17:45:11 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Registered receiver for stream 0 from akka://sparkDriver
15/01/20 17:45:11 INFO receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Receiver started again
15/01/20 17:45:12 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:12 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743512000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:13 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:13 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743513000 ms
15/01/20 17:45:14 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
15/01/20 17:45:14 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421743514000 ms
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is no while loop (or other repeating construct) on your `socket.receive` function. It receives one 1024-bit packet, stores it, and then closes the socket. This receiver can't receive more than one packet. Spark tries to restart your receiver twice, and then fails.

Comment: I tried after adding While(!isStopped()) loop, both after and before creating socket, but that doesn't work either. Checkout my updated code at the same gist address. (https://gist.github.com/d34th4ck3r/0e88896eac864d6d7193)

Comment: That's normal. You need to loop on whether your data source still has packets to provide. Take inspiration from the code in `SocketInputDStream` !

Comment: Can you be more precise ?

Comment: 1. Assume your stream has 2048 bits to send on the UDP socket. Walk through the steps of how your Receivers reacts to that.

2. Compare with the TCP socket in SocketInputDStream located here: 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/SocketInputDStream.scala

Notice the while loop. Notice it's not just conditioned `isStopped`. Think how you would add an equivalent of the other condition on your case. 

3. Combine 1 + 2, concluding on what you need to loop on. 

4. vote on answers to questions you asked.

Comment: Thanks! But actually this solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153247/spark-streaming-not-performing-operations-on-read-blocks. My looping was correct but I was not having enough slots.